# Check files in list from file (doesn't) exist in directory works fine, but also search in subdirectories

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have a working script where I have a file with filenames and search for that filename in a directory. If it's found, create `filesfound.txt`, and if not then `filesNOTfound.txt`. So far I'm already really happy this is working. Only I just noticed that the files I'm looking for are in a lot of subdirectories, for example:

```
archive_documents/239496/10091299/
archive_documents/433144/10118552/
```

etc

How can I start in `archive_documents` but also search in the subdirectories?

This I have so far. Testing local first with cygdrive:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Check Files in list from file exist or doesn't exist in directory.

if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "You must pass the path to file with the list and the path to directory to check files. \nsh check-file-exist-from-list.sh path/to/file path/to/directory"
    exit 1
fi

while IFS=$'\t\r' read -r file; do 
    if [ -e "$2/$file" ]; then
        echo "$file" >> /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/filesfound.txt
    else
        echo "$file" >> /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/filesNOTfound.txt
    fi
done < "$1"
```

I start this by:

```
./test.sh /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/file_list.txt \
          /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/test
```

In the directory `test` there are subfolders, but I don't know how to include them. I've searched for a lot of things already like `type -d` but don't know how to fit it in.

Comment: Use `find` to search the directory tree rooted at each given starting-point

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (contents of the file `file_list.txt` that contains the list of paths to files you want to check, plus some specific paths to files in your directory structure that cause whatever the problem is you have), and the expected output given that file contents and that directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested starting point at least, assuming none of your file names contain newlines:

```
awk -v outdir='/cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/' '
    NR == FNR {
        present[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        print > (outdir "files" ($0 in present ? "" : "NOT") "found.txt")
    }
' <(find "$2" -type f -printf '%P\n') "$1"
```

The above assumes the paths in your input file match the paths printed by `find`, i.e. are relative to the directory you pass in as `$2`, if not then massage that file and/or the `find` options or `awk` script to suit.

Here is the above (tweaked to print results to stdout rather than files just for convenience here) running in a script as I think you are trying to do:

```
$ find /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/test -type f -printf '%P\n'
bar/that
foo/this
```

```
$ cat /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/file_list.txt
foo/this
bar/that
bar/theSkyIsFalling
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v outdir='/cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/' '
    NR == FNR {
        present[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        print $0, ($0 in present ? "" : "NOT ") "found"
    }
' <(find "$2" -type f -printf '%P\n') "$1"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/file_list.txt /cygdrive/c/temp/shellscript/test
foo/this found
bar/that found
bar/theSkyIsFalling NOT found
```

Comment: thanks for your time to reply. I used your code but so far I get the same result as with my original code. To make sure I did it right, I replaced my code from the "while" all the way down. I just don't understand why it will not find the test_d.txt in ../test/sub/

Comment: I edited my answer to show my script running. If that isn't what you wanted then please edit your question to make it clear what you want.